# Select TOP 1000 + custom user id's

Tags: teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I want to select top 1000 user id's based on revenue in addition to a custom list of user id's (these are not part of the top 1000)

In other words, I want the queries below in 1 query:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM XX
ORDER BY REVENUE DESC

SELECT * FROM XX
WHERE USER_ID IN (CUSTOM_LIST)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Union, but as TOP is not allowed in a Set-Select you must nest it in a Derived Table:

```
SELECT *
FROM
 (
   SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM XX
   ORDER BY REVENUE DESC
 ) as dt

 UNION
  -- UNION ALL is more efficient, but a user from the custom list who is 
  -- also in the top 1000 would be returned twice

SELECT * FROM XX
WHERE USER_ID IN (CUSTOM_LIST)
```

Comment: When I order by Revenue I get duplicate user id's, since I am aggregating on day level. How can I get top 1000 without the duplicate user id's?

Comment: @StephenTheunissen: You have to apply Distinct before Top. How does your actual Select look like, probably not `select *`?

Comment: Top N Syntax error: Top N option is not supported with DISTINCT option. I thought about it as well, but it doesn't seem to work. SELECT DAY, WEEK, MONTH, USER_ID, REVENUE, and a bunch of other metrics.

Comment: @StephenTheunissen: Distinct will not help in this case (it needs to be nested again). Which row shuld be returned when the same USER_ID is returned multiple times, the highest or the earliest/latest one? Is the Revenue reuslt of an aggregation or just a column?

Comment: Solved the issue, your answer helped me a lot!